# Can't .net project mongodb connection .Whats wrong

Tags: c#, .net, database, mongodb, connection

My context Class

```
 public class Context
    {
        private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;
        public Context(IOptions<Settings> settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
            _database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);

        }
        public IMongoCollection<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>()
        {
            return _database.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name.Trim());
        }
        public IMongoDatabase GetDatabase()
        {
            return _database;
        }
    }
```

My AppsettingJson

```
"MongoConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://username:mypassword@mongodb.net/ODSDataBase?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "Database": "ODSDataBase"
```

My Settings class

```
public class Settings
    {
        public string ConnectionString;

        public string Database;
    }
```

My Repository injection

private readonly Context.Context _context;
private readonly IMongoCollection _collection;

```
public MongoRepositoryBase(IOptions<Settings> settings)
        
{
     _context = new Context.Context(settings);            
     _collection=_context.GetCollection<TEntity>();
}
```

Comment: I want to connect my .net project to mongodb but I can't. I can't solve my problem

Comment: your above code doesn't say what you did as well as what error you see, what options you specify and etc

Answer (score -1):

you can use this github to check your code

https://github.com/MohammadAsadi1372/TestMongoDB/tree/master/TestMongoDB

and this link is use mongo in docker

https://github.com/MohammadAsadi1372/TestMongoDB